# Error Number: 1048 Column 'btc' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, mysqli

This code shows

> Error Number: 1048

Column 'btc' cannot be null

but actually I am sending everything right, I even tried parameters with URL but still it says that btc can not be null. whats wrong

```
    $date='';
        $timezone = "Asia/Karachi";
        if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        $date=date('d-m-Y | H:i:s');
    $data=array(
        'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
        'btc' => $this->input->post('btc'),
        'networkfee' => $this->input->post('networkfee'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'riseupfee' => $this->input->post('riseupfee'),
        'date' => $date,
        'status' => 'Sent'
    );
    $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    $data = $this->ajax_model->withdraw_btc($data);
```

Sending ajax request.

```
   $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:{btc: '0.0001', address: 'xxxx', risupfee: '0.001', 
   networkfee: '0.0001'},
                url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/withdraw_btc'); ?>',
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);


                }
```

Comment: i even tried http://localhost/riseup/ajax/withdraw_btc?btc=123 but still it shows btc can not be null

Comment: `print_r($data)` what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database settings for 'btc' row. You are probably sending wrong type